# add android studio to PATH environmental variable?

Tags: path, android

I looked around some sites and yielded no success. I tried to modify `.bashrc`:

```
# User specific aliases and functions
export PATH="~/android-studio/bin/:$PATH"
```

and after I typed `studio.sh` on the shell it says no such file or directory.

Comment: is `studio.sh` executeable? And did you re-source your bashrc (`source ~/.bashrc`). Lastly I normally use `${HOME}` instead of `~` for my path variable.

Comment: Yes, as I could run `file/path/to/studio.sh` to start up android studio. what do you mean by re-sourcing bashrc?

Comment: just type "source ~/.bashrc" After you change your bashrc, nothing happens. It only takes effect when you source it, which happens when you open a new terminal

Answer (score 1):

add the following line to .bashrc

```
export PATH=~/Documents/android-studio/bin:$PATH
```

save and execute the following command....

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

enter `studio.sh` and it should open

Comment: The issue in the question is the tilde, and the fact that it's not expanded to the home directory when it's quoted.

Comment: @Thomas How does a suggestion which solves the problem not provide an answer the question? Taking this to review is ridiculous.